# How to mock a third-party api calls in the backend

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, supertest

I'm testing my application with mocha and supertest, so my test always are like

```
var request = require('supertest'),
    app = require('./bootstrap.js');

describe('...', function() {
  it('...', function() {
    request(app)
      .get('/some/url')
      // ...
  });
```

});

the bootstrap.js is my real application before listen ports

all works perfect but recently I have to add calls to a third-party API and testing is slow

so when I do, the test for example takes 5 seconds

```
request(app)
  .get('/my/endpoint/that/makes/call/others')
  // ...
```

**How I can make fake calls during the test but real when running my application?**

Comment: Where did you add the 3rd party API calls? Can you share the code for bootstrap.js?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nock](https://github.com/node-nock/nock) for that purpose.